# Make Django 3 REST render HTML template

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I am trying to build a Django (version 3.05) REST API call that will render to a chosen HTML template.

I am, however, receiving a number of errors that I haven't found a solution to on StackOverflow (And yes, I've looked far and wide).

Since my errors are many and varying depending on what I attempt, let me rather ask how to do it correctly to begin with.

In my view set up (below), what do I need to add (or change) in order to render the queryset to an HTML template?

models.py:

```
from django.db import models
class Hero(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    alias = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

serializers.py:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import Hero
class HeroSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Hero
        fields = ('name', 'alias')
```

views.py:

```
from rest_framework import viewsets
from .serializers import HeroSerializer
from .models import Hero
class HeroViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Hero.objects.all().order_by('name')
    serializer_class = HeroSerializer
    # over here - how do I render the queryset /to/my/template.html
```

myapi/urls.py:

```
from django.urls import include, path
from rest_framework import routers
from . import views
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'heroes', views.HeroViewSet)
```

Comment: What do you mean "render to a chosen html template"?  Is this a django html template, from the old days?  Are you trying to get the browseable API pages?  Do you want to render HTML as the response directly so that you can include it in your page, and if so can you provide the API call you would make, and the expected output?

Comment: @AndrewBacker thank you - yes, preferably an old-school Django template. I am not trying to get browsable API pages, but rather exploring the most efficient way of making information available to both API calls and templates. With external calls I'd like to return an API result (for which the current REST framework is useful), but then, also, if the method is being called from links within my app, return the information in the appropriate template (containing lots of gui menus etc).

Answer (score -1):

you should change your view from ModelViewSet to APIView.
with API view you can include renderer_classes and template_name.

check [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/html-and-forms/#rendering-html) for more information

Comment: Thank you for this - unfortunately I had already tried your link in one of my many initial attempts. I repeatedly got the error "Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: context must be a dict rather than ReturnList." following the "return Response({'heroes': queryset}) in the final line of my views (which I adjusted to be just like the example you posted)

Comment: You can set *any* property on a ViewSet that you can set on an APIView.  One inherits from the other.